# Copying rows from a worksheet to 4 different worksheets

Tags: excel, copy, copy-paste, vba

Please suggest how to copy rows of data from one worksheet to 4 different worksheets for

a. Previous month

b. Current year YTD

c. Previous year month

d. Previous year YTD

Comment: Can you please be a bit more clear. Also please share any code snippets you have tried so far.

Comment: Can you please add an example of your input and desired output ?

Comment: There is one sheet that contains lifetime data and one of the columns in the sheet is a date column. Based on this column, we'll have to copy matching rows in the other sheets.

Answer (score 0):

You can access any cell of any worksheet using
`Sheet("Sheetname").Cells(rownumber, columnnumber)` if you know the name of the worksheets or `Sheet(index).Cells(rownumber,columnumber)` if only the index of the worksheets are fixed.
To copy the value you can just write `Sheet(index1).Cells(rownumber1, columnnumber1)=Sheet(index2).Cells(rownumber2, columnnumber2)`

You can select a whole row as well by `Rows(index).Select` or multiple rows by `Rows("startIndex:endIndex").Select`